# Where is the best place to initialise a database in a Svelte app

Tags: database, svelte

So I have a Svelte app that uses data from a better-sqlite3 database. The app pulls data from the database and stores it in a Svelte store. The app also initialises the database and creates tables if they don't exist already. I'm struggling to work out the best place to do the DB init. Currently, it's at the start of my Store.js because that's where it works but it feels wrong and I'm wondering if I might not be making trouble for myself.

By way of illustration below is a link to a REPL that approximates what's going on without the database stuff.

https://svelte.dev/repl/54e5787a37ff47bb9f72476dab67d3b1?version=3.35.0

Answer (score 0):

From an architectural standpoint you should not be doing database operations and initialization in the client as this exposes a high security issue. For that you should use a separate backend (e.g. a NodeJS server) that serves the data via Rest. This server can initialize your database on start.

Comment: Even if this is local use only?

Comment: If it's local: Why nog play arround first with a "local persistent svelte store".

Comment: I'm not familiar but I'll be needing data in the 100s of megabytes and fast searching. BetterS]-sqlite3 seemed like a good fit and I'm familiar with it.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that running database queries from the client's browser can block the event loop which will lead to a slow & potentially blocking UI. That's why you'd typically let your backend system handle that kind of stuff. You could then use the svelte store as a kind of cache as it is pretty fast to read data from there. However if you want to initialize your db in the client then your main.js/ts would be a good place for doing that as that's the app's entry point.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but Store.js, strangely, gets called before main.js.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late but I hope it helps. Sveltekit recommends storing server-only operations like accessing a database or making requests to a backend server in a special +page.server.js/.ts file for each route.

Additionally for initializing the database, you can create a db.ts file in the $lib/server directory. The files and functions that those files export will never be sent to the client. If you try and access them in a way that is unsafe, i.e. would expose them to the client, then Svelte would complain and wouldn't compile. For more details refer to: [Server Only Modules](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/server-only-modules)

Then you can use the DB in the individual routes by calling it from +page.server.ts files. This way the database and any other critical information won't be sent to the client.

I use it like this:

- Database initialization and setup e.g. table creation and such are done in the db.ts file inside the $lib/server directory.
- I define my schema inside $lib/server/schema.ts
- I do not access the database instance directly from the page routes. Instead, I export functions from the $lib/server directory which are used in the +page.server.ts file.

I hope this helped. Also on a side note make a separate db directory inside $lib/server to better organize the files.